# Sass selector that checks if a class is on any ancestor

Tags: css, sass, selector, parent, ancestor

Is it possible to write a Sass selector that targets an element which has an ancestor that has a certain class applied?

```
<div class="fruit">
    <div class="tree">
        <div class="apple">
            <div class="seed">I want this to go red.</div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div class="bush">
        <div class="raspberry">
            <div class="seed">I don't want this to go red.<div>
        </div>
    <div>
<div>
```

is it possible to write some kind of Sass like this?

```
.seed :ancestor-selector(.tree) {
    color: red;
}
```

...and have the "I want this to go red" actually turn red?

Here is a pen you can play with to try and make it work:
https://codepen.io/timrhaynes/pen/xxGNppx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is. You can use `&` like this:

```
.seed {
    .tree & {
        /** Wow! I'm seed in tree! */
        color: red;
    }
}
```

You can read more about Parent Selector in [Sass documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector).

Comment: Sadly, this does not work. Check out the pen here: https://codepen.io/timrhaynes/pen/xxGNppx

Comment: It works. You just didn't close your `div` tag. Check generated CSS. Fixed your typo: https://codepen.io/Jaxp/pen/YzXoXoj

Comment: Oh dang, you are right! Thank you, this is perfect :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the ampersand *after* your specific case is possible.

```
.seed {

  color: green;

  .tree & {

    color: red;

  }
}
```

To answer directly. I think not, while CSS likes to start thinking at the root and then organize towards the 'leaves', as you are probably guessing as well.